# Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'contains'

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have used jQuery `.contain()` method in my project it is working fine in Firefox but gives error in Google Chrome. My code looks like this:

```
if (txtsearchvalue.contains('-')) {
  var Arraytxtsearchvalue = [];   
  Arraytxtsearchvalue = txtsearchvalue.split('-');
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Object `17-331-250251-92` has no method 'contains'

In Chrome 47 error message is:

> Uncaught TypeError: txtsearchvalue.contains is not a function

Comment: what is txtsearchvalue?

Comment: once use `$(txtsearchvalue)` instead of just `txtsearchvalue`. might work.

Comment: @canon - Yes, sorry, I meant to say jQuery objects don't have a `.contains()` method (but there is `$.contains()`). Either way I doubt that `txtsearchvalue` is a jQuery object anyway, and if it is there'll be an error on `txtsearchvalue.split()`.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a [`contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) method but it doesn't work like you think it does; specifically, it doesn't work with text. jQuery also has a [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) *selector* which is closer to what you *seem* to want...

That said, my suspicion is that `txtsearchvalue` is a string rather than a jQuery object. FireFox has a [`String.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) method while Chrome does not.

Mozilla has a polyfill for their non-standard method ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains#Polyfill)):

```
if(!('contains' in String.prototype))
    String.prototype.contains = function(str, startIndex) { 
        return -1 !== String.prototype.indexOf.call(this, str, startIndex); 
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
if (txtsearchvalue.indexOf('-') > -1) {  
   var Arraytxtsearchvalue = [];   
   Arraytxtsearchvalue = txtsearchvalue.split('-'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

```js
const sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

const word = 'fox';

console.log(`The word "${word}" ${sentence.includes(word) ? 'is' : 'is not'} in the sentence`);
```